# How can I make Async IO work on a non async function?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a complex function `Vehicle.set_data`, which has many nested functions, API calls, DB calls, etc. For the sake of this example, I will simplify it.

I am trying to use Async IO to run `Vehicle.set_data` on multiple vehicles at once. Here is my `Vehicle` model:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    # Works async
    async def set_data(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 10)

    # Does not work async
    # def set_data(self):
    #     time.sleep(random.random() * 10)
```

And here is my Async IO routinue:

```
async def set_vehicle_data(vehicle):
    # sleep for T seconds on average
    await vehicle.set_data()


def get_random_string():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))


async def producer(queue):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        # produce a token and send it to a consumer
        token = get_random_string()
        vehicle = Vehicle(token)
        print(f'produced {vehicle.token}')
        await queue.put(vehicle)
        if count > 3:
            break


async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        vehicle = await queue.get()
        # process the token received from a producer
        print(f'Starting consumption for vehicle {vehicle.token}')
        await set_vehicle_data(vehicle)
        queue.task_done()
        print(f'Ending consumption for vehicle {vehicle.token}')


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # @todo now, do I need multiple producers
    producers = [asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
                 for _ in range(3)]
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
                 for _ in range(3)]

    # with both producers and consumers running, wait for
    # the producers to finish
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    print('---- done producing')

    # wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
    await queue.join()

    # cancel the consumers, which are now idle
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()


asyncio.run(main())
```

In the example above, this commented section of code does not allow multiple vehicles to process at once:

```
    # Does not work async
    # def set_data(self):
    #     time.sleep(random.random() * 10)
```

Because this is such a complex query in our actual codebase, it would be a tremendous refactor to go flag every single nested function with `async` and `await`. Is there any way I can make this function work async without marking up my whole codebase with `async`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the function in a separate thread with [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)

```py
await asyncio.to_thread(self.set_data)
```

If you're using python <3.9 use [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.set_data)
```